# if statement, doesn't work

Tags: expect

I've the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

pw=$1
pw2=$2
file=$3
user="admin"

if [ $# -eq 0 ]
        then
                echo "bitte PW und IP-file als Parameter angeben"
fi


for ip in `cat $file`;
        do
                ping -c1 $ip >/dev/null 2>&1
                if [ $? -eq 0 ];  
                        then      
                                echo $ip
                                /usr/bin/expect <<EOD
                                spawn /usr/bin/telnet $ip
                                if { expect "Please Enter Password:" } {
                                        send $pw\r }
                                } elseif{ expect "Please Enter Login Name:" } {
                                        send $user\r
                                        send $pw\r }
                                expect telnet@*
                                send ena\r
                                expect "Password:"
                                send $pw2\r
                                expect "telnet@*"
                                send skip-page-display\r
                                expect telnet@*
                                send "show running-config\r"
                                log_file "$ip.conf"
                                expect "telnet@*"
                                send "exit\r"
                                expect "telnet@*"
                                send "exit\rn"
EOD                               
                else              
                        echo "$i nicht erreicht"
fi                                
done
```

but it didn't work, I got the following error:

```
spawn /usr/bin/telnet IP
invalid bareword "expect"
in expression " expect "Please Enter Passwor...";
should be "$expect" or "{expect}" or "expect(...)" or ...
    (parsing expression " expect "Please Enter ...")
    invoked from within
"if { expect "Please Enter Password:" } {
                                        send top_SECRET\r }"
```

any ideas how I get this to work?
Some Switches have need a username, some others doesn't, so I need an If-Statement to check what ist expected.
Thanks in advance for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You conditionally expect different things by using expect with several pattern/acction pairs, and use `exp_continue`. Instead of

```
if { expect "Please Enter Password:" } {
    send $pw\r }
} elseif { expect "Please Enter Login Name:" } {
    send $user\r
    send $pw\r 
}
expect telnet@*
```

Do this

```
expect {
    "Please Enter Password:"   { send $pw\r; exp_continue }
    "Please Enter Login Name:" { send $user\r$pw\r; exp_continue }
    telnet@*
}
```

You had an error: `elseif` requires a space between it and the open brace. And yes, `expect` is unknown to a Tcl expression ([docs](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/expr.htm))

After you `send exit`, you should `expect eof`

Answer (score 0):

As the [TCL reference documentation shows](http://tmml.sourceforge.net/doc/tcl/if.html), `if` requires an expression as its condition.

> if expr1 ?then? body1 elseif expr2 ?then? body2 elseif ... ?else? ?bodyN?

`expect "string"` is not a valid expression as evaluated by `expr`.

Comment: thanks for this information, but how can i solve it?